# Catch Access Denied Exception when trying to write to a file in C++ on Unix

Tags: c++, exception, permissions, file-transfer

I‘m writing a file transfer program in C++ on Unix that works via TCP Sockets.
But whenever the client receives the binary bytes and tries to save them into a file, then I‘m asked whether I allow the program to access the Desktop. If the user denies access, then how do you catch this exception ?

```
FILE *binaryFile = fopen(absolutePath, “wb“);
fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, binaryFile);
```

Do you have any ideas, websites ... ?

Thx

Comment: check the result of `fopen` then `errno` to see why it failed?

Comment: The asking is a function of whatever desktop environment you're using. If you want to handle this case specifically, you need to write a program specifically for that desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply putting it in a try catch
I changed this to c++

```
try 
{ 
    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.exceptions ( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );
    uint8_t bytes[] = { 0x55, 0x48, 0x89, 0xe5, 0xbf, 0x00, 00, 00, 00, 0xe8, 00, 00, 00, 00, 0xb8, 00, 00, 00, 00, 0x5d, 0xc3 };
    
    outfile.open("binfile.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);  
    outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(bytes), sizeof bytes);
}   
catch (const std::exception& e) 
{ 
    std::cout << "exception caught" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `fopen` is a c function so doesn't throw exceptions

Comment: @AlanBirtles good point I changed my code to pure c+++

Comment: `std::ofstream` doesn't throw exceptions either unless you call the `exceptions` method

Comment: @PaulBaxter Thanks for your Support, but whenever I deny the access then it still throws (lldb) Error ;(

Comment: @AlanBirtles  I added the exceptions call

Comment: @AES2048 if you're getting an error in lldb you should edit that error message into your question